# Multiple Environments and CRON with PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron

On my CodeIgniter site, I use something like this to distinguish between live and dev environments.

```
if (defined('STDIN') || $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']=='livesite.com') {
    define('ENVIRONMENT', 'production');
} else {
    define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');
}
```

Then, based on environment my code sets up proper database configurations.

I also have several CRON jobs that run via PHP, effectively running certain code within the site.

When I run CRON jobs that work with this code, they seem to just default to production environment. So all the CRONs I run on dev are still connecting to production database. How can I modify the code above to play nice with CRON as well? I just need a way to detect if CRON is being run on production or dev as well so that it will connect to respective DB.

Comment: Define an ENV variable & check on that? You can set environmental variables in your crontab file, and use `SetEnv` in apache, so both cli & webserver both check the same thing & know where they are.

Comment: @Wrikken can you elaborate or link to any examples? First time working with CRON in general.

Comment: You can do it directly in the crontab. Edit the crontab and add the following line on the top of your crons 
#Crons running from the cluster
SERVER_NAME="VARIABLE TO MATCH THE CONDITION"

Comment: or you can have an env variable something like 
SITE_DATA="DEV" and use that in the if condition $_SERVER["SITE_DATA"]

Comment: I prefer using `getenv()`, but for the rest: as Abhik says. `man 5 crontab` will probably tell you all you need to know.

Comment: These comments sound like great options. You guys should expand a little and left actual answers; I'd certainly upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_SERVER` is not defined in cronjobs, which is why your check fails.

There are several ways to identify the environment, depending on your configuration:

```
php -B "define('ENVIRONMENT', 'test');" /path/to/cronjob.php
```

Then in the code check:

```
if (!defined('ENVIRONMENT')) {
  .. do your $_SERVER check ..
}
```

If your environments are on different hosts, you can use:

```
if (php_sapi_name() == 'cli') { // Check if it's running from console/cron
  if (trim(`uname -n`) == 'myserver.dev') { // not portable to windows
    define('ENVIRONMENT', 'test');
  } else {
    define('ENVIRONMENT', 'production');
  }
} else {
  ... do your $_SERVER check ...
}
```

You can set a cron variable, e.g.

```
*/15 * * * * ENVIRONMENT="test" php /path/to/cron
```

Then check in your script:

```
if (php_sapi_name() == 'cli') {
  // you should check if it's valid first. Left out as exercise for the reader
  define('ENVIRONMENT', $_ENV['ENVIRONMENT']);
} else {
  ... do your $_SERVER check ...
}
```

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, what does -B do? I'll give this a shot in a bit but it looks great. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you, I think it needed a semicolon after the definition. It threw one error, I fixed it but now nothing happens at all. Trying to figure out why.

Comment: What I'm seeing here is that you have to define it somewhere - there is no `$_SERVER` type variable accessible via index.php itself, maybe that has the server path to hinge on?

Comment: `$_ENV['PWD']`? Is that safe?

Comment: This answer is inaccurate. $_SERVER **is** defined in cron jobs.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me:

```
if (php_sapi_name() == 'cli') {

    switch ($_SERVER['PWD']) {
        case '/path/to/production':
            define('ENVIRONMENT', 'production');
            break;

        case '/path/to/testing':
            define('ENVIRONMENT', 'testing');
            break;

        default:
            define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');
            break;
    }

} else {

    // Not via CLI; Check $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']

}
```

Open up Terminal and run `php -i` to see what variables are available on your server that you can use. I like to default to my development environment because different developers can set up different virtual hosts or paths to their working directory.

Answer (score 0):

#### Set Var in Command Way:

```
$ CI_ENV="production" php index.php welcome/index
```

---

#### Create Bootstrap Way

You could create a bootstrap for CLI with production environment concern:

In Codeigniter webroot: `./cli-prod.php`

```
if (php_sapi_name() !== 'cli') {

    die('Access Denied');
}

define('ENVIRONMENT', 'production');

require __DIR__ . '/index.php';
```

After that, run command likes:

```
php ./cli-prod.php controller/action
```